# Azure notifications hub can't register template with content-available

Tags: swift, azure, push-notification, apple-push-notifications, azure-notificationhub

I am trying to register a template for Azure Notifications Hub for iOS with content-available field in aps and I'm having some issues regarding this. When I register a template with the following format it works:

```
"{\"aps\" : {\"alert\":\"$(message)\" }, \"payload\": { \"type\" : \"$(type)\", \"startDate\" : \"$(startDate)\", \"id\" : \"$(id)\"} }"
```

However, when I try to add content-available field, since I want to be able to send silent notifications I get an error from Azure saying it's bad request:

```
"{\"aps\" : {\"alert\":\"$(message)\", \"content-available\": \"$(content-available)\", \"sound\":\"\" }, \"payload\": { \"type\" : \"$(type)\", \"startDate\" : \"$(startDate)\", \"id\" : \"$(id)\"} }"
```

When I change "$" notation to "#" and "-" to "_" I can register sucessfully however, when I try to send notification I get an error on Azure portal saying notification payload is invalid:

```
"{\"aps\" : {\"alert\":\"$(message)\", \"content-available\": \"#(content_available)\", \"sound\":\"\" }, \"payload\": { \"type\" : \"$(type)\", \"startDate\" : \"$(startDate)\", \"sleeperId\" : \"$(sleeperId)\"} }"
```

I understand that this problem has something do to with the fact that "content-available" has "-" which Azure cannot parse.

Comment: did you try to add content-available as a separate value after "aps": ?

Comment: Just tried it, does not work, still getting the same error: "The Notification payload is invalid"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I managed to solve it, instead of 1 or 0 you should put true/false. So the code for content-available in the template should look like this:

```
\"content-available\": \"#(content_available)\"
```

And when sending the notification put

```
content-available: true
```

This eliminates notification payload error and you receive silent notification in the background. Also make sure that alert and sound are empty strings.